# Show spinner when data is loading on react

Tags: reactjs, spinner, state, loader

i'm having some trouble showing the spinner "" when i'm getting some data. I have a state.isLoading but i can't seem to set that to true before the getdata.getPossible() function starts. Heres what i have:

```
class GetData extends Component {
  constructor() {
    super();
    this.state = {
      lastdraw: {},
      alldraws: [],
      bets: [],
      isLoading: false,
      showBets: false 
    };
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    getdata.getLastResult().then((result) => {
      this.setState({lastdraw: result.data.drawns[0]})
    })
  }

  getMore() {
    this.setState({isLoading: !this.state.isLoading})
    this.setState({bets: getdata.getPossible(5), showBets: !this.state.showBets})
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <h1>{this.props.title}</h1>
        <h3>{moment(this.state.lastdraw.date).format('LL')}</h3>
        <div><span>{this.state.lastdraw.numbers}</span> + <span>{this.state.lastdraw.stars}</span></div>
        <Btn onClick={this.getMore.bind(this)}>Generate</Btn>
        {this.state.showBets ? this.state.bets.map((bet, i) => {return (<PossibleKey key={this.state.bets[i].key} bets={bet}/>)}) : null}
        <Loader show={this.state.isLoading}/>
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

And the Loader component is like this:

```
function Loader(props) {
    return props.show ? (
        <div className='overlay'>
          <div className='leftEye'></div>
          <div className='rightEye'></div>
          <div className='mouth'></div>
          <p>The Universe is aligning. Please wait...</p>
        </div>
    ) : null
}
```

What i want to achieve is a way for the loader component to be used elsewhere just by setting the isLoading state true or false. The getMore() function only triggers the Loader state after it executes getPossible(n).

I think it may be something to do with the Loader receiving props only after state is set (or maybe not!!). How can i trigger the Loader on/off ?!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to do something after state has updated - you can pass a callback to state method like this

```
getMore() {
  this.setState({isLoading: !this.state.isLoading}, () => {
    this.setState({bets: getdata.getPossible(5), showBets: !this.state.showBets})      
  })
}
```

This should set the state isLoading before `getPossible` is called

Comment: I took your suggestion and made this and a click handler: `handleClick() {
    this.setState((prevState, props) => ({
      isloading: true
    }))
    getdata.getPossible(5).then(result => {
      this.setState((prevState, props) => ({
        bets: result
      }))
    })
    .then((done) => {
      this.setState((prevState, props) => ({
        isloading: false
      }))
    })

  }`. It works, it's not the most elegant code ever, with the promises. Else i would have to lift the loading state to the parent component, or even further and pass down as props.

Comment: You can see the all code at: https://github.com/talvasconcelos/millions

Answer (score 2):

Sometimes the issue is sequencing the `setState`. Try this:

```
 getMore() {
    this.setState({isLoading: !this.state.isLoading}, () => {
      this.setState({bets: getdata.getPossible(5), showBets: !this.state.showBets})
    })
  }
```

Comment: Lol! We answered the same damn thing

Comment: I'd allready tried that with no luck!! :( Once again it runs the getPossible first and then triggers the Loader.

Comment: @ArshabhAgarwal haah :D

Answer (score 1):

Is this your target?

```
  getMore() {
    if (!this.state.isLoading) {
      this.setState({isLoading: !this.state.isLoading, bets: getdata.getPossible(5), showBets: !this.state.showBets})
    }
  }
```

Comment: Yes. Want i'm trying to do is set the loading state to true, then run the getdata.getPossible

Comment: In my version of code you check next status of isLoading, and then run getPossible and during set isLoading. And in this way not so important the ordering setting the state, i think. After the and working setState methis all data will be right(if you not use the isLoading inside getPossible, in this way could run getPossible(isLoading) - where isLoading = !this.state.isLoading and set it before the run setState) :)